# Rails remote true does not work sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem where remote true submits form with js for most users but for some others it generates an html request instead that causes an error. Any ideas why remote may not work in certain scenarios?

Can it be that some users disable javascript? What can I do in such scenarios? Any other possible reasons? Happens on IE 10, Safari 6, Chrome 32, Android 4.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some users have disabled javascript.

You can test this by disabling javascript and trying to use your form.

In the case users disable javascript, ideally you should have the form still work and return a proper html response. If this is not an option then you need detect that users are not using javascript using the  tags and warn them the site will not work.

Comment: Thanks upisdown. How do I detect that javascript is not working?